# Forwarding to third party url with post and passing parameter in Java Servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am using servlet and jsp. I need to go to another server address like (167.92.10.......) from my localhost(http://localhost:8080/DSC/index.jsp).

While going , I need to use POST Method with some parameters. Then that server

redirects to another address if my passing parameters are correct.

I need to show these all things that are happening in web . Currently I am using following code to hit another address (167.92.10.......). My question is how can I show these all things that are happening in web?

```
    public void Hit(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,String base64) throws Exception {

      URL url = new URL("http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx/abgc/gdfgdfg");
        Map<String,Object> params = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        params.put("bharrkkosh", base64);


        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> param : params.entrySet()) {
            if (postData.length() != 0) postData.append('&');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(param.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
            postData.append('=');
            postData.append(URLEncoder.encode(String.valueOf(param.getValue()), "UTF-8"));
        }
        byte[] postDataBytes = postData.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");

        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(postDataBytes.length));
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.getOutputStream().write(postDataBytes);


        Reader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));

        for (int c; (c = in.read()) >= 0;)
        {
            System.out.print((char)c);

        }


    }
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: I edited my question , my question is in last line.

Comment: Where do you want this to show?In browser address bar,well then you need to use sendRedirect() for directing from browser end.